# preparedStatement.getBigDecimal where the value is null

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a prepared statement that works great when there is a value in all the columns but when there is a null I get this error.

```
Bad value for type BigDecimal : N
```

Note the error is thrown when I try to use:

> priceListResult.getBigDecimal(6);

My Google foo is letting me down, I am having trouble finding any info on this. I'd have thought this would be a fairly common problem.

Any help, or even background info to help me search this, much appreciated.

Comment: Closest my google-fu could find is [this](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Bad-value-for-type-BigDecimal-Y-td2175427.html)

Comment: Can you check that column 6 is indeed a numeric type?

Comment: @Thomas yeah I had a look at that, I'm reasonably confident that's not the issue I'm having.

Comment: @Reimeus Yeah it's numeric(10,0), I wonder if the 0 precision means I need to use get int? will try that.

Comment: @Reimeus, looks like you were right I was looking at the wrong column so had the wrong type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will post as a stock solution for this problem:

```
When dealing with the following 

    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type BigDecimal : Y
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.toBigDecimal(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2710)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getBigDecimal(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2133
```

the main source or error is malformed SQL. Always check your syntax.

Answer (score 1):

My bad,

I missed a comma in my SQL so the count was off. Not sure why this did not throw an error?